# WebRTC STUN/TURN allocate request timed out

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm testing the WebRTC video calling API.
For signaling Firestore is being used.
Offer is being created in caller web browser A and sent to callee B, which then returns the answer to A. Then `icecandidates` are being shared where I'm facing the problem described below -

1. Chrome not showing any error in console. But when I head over to [chrome://webrtc-internals/](http://chrome://webrtc-internals/), I see multiple `icecandidateerror` error logs -

```html
// replaced real IP with x.x.x.x
// following errors from 
icecandidateerror{
  url: turn:numb.viagenie.ca:3478?transport=udp
  address: x.x.x.x
  port: 55791
  host_candidate: x.x.x.x:55791
  error_text: TURN allocate request timed out.
  error_code: 701
}
icecandidateerror{
  url: stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302
  address: x.x.x.x
  port: 55791
  host_candidate: x.x.x.x:55791
  error_text: STUN allocate request timed out.
  error_code: 701
}
.....total of 8 such errors

// following logs are from webrtc-internals_dump.txt
{
     "time": "7/28/2020, 9:14:57 PM",
     "type": "icecandidateerror",
     "value": "url: turn:numb.viagenie.ca:3478?transport=udp\naddress: x.x.x.x\nport: 55787\nhost_candidate: x.x.x.x:55787\nerror_text: TURN allocate request timed out.\nerror_code: 701"
    },
    {
     "time": "7/28/2020, 9:14:57 PM",
     "type": "icecandidateerror",
     "value": "url: turn:numb.viagenie.ca:3478?transport=udp\naddress: x.x.x.x\nport: 55791\nhost_candidate: x.x.x.x:55791\nerror_text: TURN allocate request timed out.\nerror_code: 701"
    },
    {
     "time": "7/28/2020, 9:14:57 PM",
     "type": "icecandidateerror",
     "value": "url: stun:numb.viagenie.ca:3478\naddress: x.x.x.x\nport: 55787\nhost_candidate: x.x.x.x:55787\nerror_text: STUN allocate request timed out.\nerror_code: 701"
    },
    {
     "time": "7/28/2020, 9:14:57 PM",
     "type": "icecandidateerror",
     "value": "url: stun:numb.viagenie.ca:3478\naddress: x.x.x.x\nport: 55791\nhost_candidate: x.x.x.x:55791\nerror_text: STUN allocate request timed out.\nerror_code: 701"
    },
    {
     "time": "7/28/2020, 9:14:57 PM",
     "type": "icecandidateerror",
     "value": "url: stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302\naddress: x.x.x.x\nport: 55787\nhost_candidate: x.x.x.x:55787\nerror_text: STUN allocate request timed out.\nerror_code: 701"
    },
    {
     "time": "7/28/2020, 9:14:57 PM",
     "type": "icecandidateerror",
     "value": "url: stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302\naddress: x.x.x.x\nport: 55791\nhost_candidate: x.x.x.x:55791\nerror_text: STUN allocate request timed out.\nerror_code: 701"
    },
    {
     "time": "7/28/2020, 9:14:57 PM",
     "type": "icecandidateerror",
     "value": "url: stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302\naddress: x.x.x.x\nport: 55787\nhost_candidate: x.x.x.x:55787\nerror_text: STUN allocate request timed out.\nerror_code: 701"
    },
    {
     "time": "7/28/2020, 9:14:57 PM",
     "type": "icecandidateerror",
     "value": "url: stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302\naddress: x.x.x.x\nport: 55791\nhost_candidate: x.x.x.x:55791\nerror_text: STUN allocate request timed out.\nerror_code: 701"
    },
```

Here one thing to notice is that the IP address `x.x.x.x` is IP address of my ethernet but I'm connected to internet via wifi. Is this be the actual problem?

[image]

2. Firefox console error -

   ```
   WebRTC: ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details
   ```

Code Sample:

```js
// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "xx-xx",
        authDomain: "xx",
        databaseURL: "https://txx.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "xx-xx-xx",
        storageBucket: "xx",
        messagingSenderId: "xx",
        appId: "xx",
        measurementId: "xx"
    };

    const servers = {
        iceServers: [
            {
                urls: [
                    'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
                    'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'
                ],
            },
            {   'urls': 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca','credential': 'xzx','username': 'xx'}
        ],
        iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    var app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    var localStream;
    var remoteStream;
    var peerConnection;

    var localVideo = document.querySelector('#localVideo')
    var remoteVideo = document.querySelector('#remoteVideo')

    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const userID = Math.round(Math.random()*1000)
    const collection = db.collection('rooms')
    var roomRef = null
    var roomID = null

    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers)
    pc.onicecandidate = event => {
        console.log('ice candidate')
        if(event.candidate) {
            roomRef.update({ iceCandidates: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({ ice: event.candidate.toJSON(), id: userID}) })
        } 
        else console.log('Sent all ice candidates!')
    }
    // this is deprecated
    // pc.onaddstream = (event => remoteVideo.srcObject = event.stream);

    async function createRoom(){
        await getLocalStream()
       
        pc.createOffer()
        .then(async (offer) => {
            roomRef = await collection.add({ id: userID, offer: { sdp: offer.sdp, type: 'offer' }})
            console.log(`New room created with ID ${roomRef.id}`)
            document.querySelector('#room-id').value = roomRef.id
            return offer
        })
        .then(offer => pc.setLocalDescription(offer))
        .then(() => attachRoomUpdateHandler())
    }

    async function joinRoom(){
        roomID = window.prompt('Enter room id', null)
        if(roomID){
            await getLocalStream()
            console.log(roomID)
            roomRef = collection.doc(roomID)
            const roomSnapshot = await roomRef.get()
            console.log(roomSnapshot,roomSnapshot.exits)
            
            var roomData = roomSnapshot.data()
            console.log(roomData.offer)
            pc.setRemoteDescription(roomData.offer)

            pc.createAnswer()
            .then(answer => pc.setLocalDescription(answer))
            .then(() => roomRef.update({ answers: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({ sdp: pc.localDescription.sdp, id: userID}) }))
            .then(() => attachRoomUpdateHandler())
      }
    }

    async function attachRoomUpdateHandler(){
        roomRef.onSnapshot(async snapshot => {
            var updatedRoomData = snapshot.data()
            if(updatedRoomData){
                if(updatedRoomData.iceCandidates){
                    var remoteIceCandidates = updatedRoomData.iceCandidates.filter( ic => ic.id!=userID)
                    if(remoteIceCandidates.length>0) {
                        remoteIceCandidates.forEach(({ice}) => pc.addIceCandidate = new RTCIceCandidate(ice))
                    } else {
                        console.log('No remote ice candidates')
                    }
                } else if(updatedRoomData.id!=userID){
                    console.log('callee remote set')
                    pc.setRemoteDescription(updatedRoomData.offer)
                } else if(updatedRoomData.id==userID){
                    if(updatedRoomData.answers && updatedRoomData.answers.length){
                        pc.setRemoteDescription({ type: 'answer', sdp: updatedRoomData.answers[0].sdp})
                        console.log('answer remote set')
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    var getLocalStream = async function(){
        return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})
        .then(stream => { localStream = stream; localVideo.srcObject = stream ; return stream })
        .then(stream => stream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc.addTrack(track, localStream)))
        .then(() => {
            pc.ontrack = (event => remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0])
        })
    }

    pc.addEventListener("connectionstatechange", ev => {
        console.log(pc.connectionState, ev)
   });
```

```css
video{  max-width: 100%;  }
```

```html
<h1>Realtime communication with WebRTC</h1>

<video id="localVideo" autoplay playsinline></video>
<video id="remoteVideo" autoplay playsinline></video>
<div>
   <input type="text" id="room-id">
    <button id="createBtn" onclick="createRoom()">Create Room</button>
    <button id="joinBtn" onclick="joinRoom()">Join Room</button>
    <p id="currentRoom"></p>
</div>    
    
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

This much I could debug currently, but could not confirm whether the problem is in my code or STUN/TURN server.

**Browser versions:**

1. Chrome version: Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)
2. Firefox version: 79.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Is this issue fixed? I'm facing same issue

Comment: Hmmm..I fixed my issue, but that was in server side ( I mean wrong turn server configuration )